# BeatuifulSoup parsing logic - check if an image exists before running the code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using scraperapi.com and Bs4 to scrape urls from a website and when it can't find a specfic element it crashes the entire code

the line in question is this one which i'm using to extract the image src

`image = soup.find('img')['src']`

and I know I need to add a check to see if it exists before scraping it, something like

````
        return image[src]
    return ''```

but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone advise what i'm doing wrong?
````

Answer (score 0):

You could simply wrap the code that causes the issue into try and except blocks. That way your code should continue executing.

```py
try:
    image = soup.find('img')['src']
except:
    image = None
```